# Is there kinetic energy when speed is constant?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

When an object is moving at a constant velocity, then does it have kinetic energy, or since kinetic energy is *the change in motion*, it doesn't?

Comment: So the answer is "yes, it has kinetic energy to the tune of $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ where $m$ is the mass and $v$ is the velocity.  However, to make a better answer, I'd like to understand more what you mean by "kinetic energy is the change in motion."  That phrasing is unusual, and it doesn't lead you to the right answer, so I'm curious if you can expound on  what that phrase meant to you.  I think an understanding of how to adjust that phrasing may help you out quite a lot.

Comment: As you can see, the formula doesn't contain any derivative of $v$. Thus, it doesn't matter if the body accelerate or not, always its speed at the moment determines the kinetical energy (at the moment).

Comment: Kinetic energy is frame-dependent. It is not an absolute or invariant quantity.  If you say "object is moving," then in the frame you are using, the object has kinetic energy.  It's changing position.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course. In classical mechanics, for a non-rotating object:
$$ E_k=\frac{1}{2}mv^2 $$

The energy is defined as the property that must be transferred to an object in order to perform work on it. An object with constant speed can clearly perform work. Your definition of kinetic energy as the change in motion is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Kinetic energy is not *the change in motion* as you say. In fact it is the energy possessed by the body by virtue of its motion. It is dependent only on speed and not on change in speed. The formula is:

$E_K = \frac{1}{2} mv^2$